# Data Join with offset

Tags: sap-hana

I have below situation:

**`Table1`**

```
Field1  Field2
123     test1
234     test2
```

**`Table2`**

```
Field1  Field2
12345   test2
23245   test3
123945  test6
```

I want to join these two tables i.e. `Table1` and `Table2` where `Field1` of `table1` matches with first three characters of `field1` of `table2`.

So results here should be:

```
Table1-field1 Table1-field2 Table2-field1 Table2-field2
123           Test1         12345         Test2
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: There should be one more row in the results (`'test1'` matched with `'test6'`).

Comment: its SQL for S4 Hana

Comment: yes you are right there is one more test1 to test 6.  let me know how to achive this?

Comment: @user134806: update your question with the 2nd result row that ypercube is referring to

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I did the following:

`CREATED` the two `TABLE`s

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  t1_field1 VARCHAR (20),
  t1_field2 VARCHAR (20)
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  t2_field1 VARCHAR (20),
  t2_field2 VARCHAR (20)
);
```

And populated it with data:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('123', 'test1');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('234', 'test2');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('12345', 'test2');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('23245', 'test3');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('123945', 'test6');
```

And then ran the following SQL:

```
SELECT t1.t1_field1, t1.t1_field2, t2.t2_field1, t2.t2_field2 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE CAST(t1.t1_field1 AS VARCHAR(3)) = CAST(t2.t2_field1 AS VARCHAR(3));
```

Giving the result:

```
 t1_field1 | t1_field2 | t2_field1 | t2_field2 
-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
       123 | test1     |     12345 | test2
       123 | test1     |    123945 | test6
(2 rows)
```

This SQL works if t1_field1 and t2_field1 are both `VARCHAR`s or `INTEGER`s (and if one is `VARCHAR` and one is `INTEGER`).

This SQL works if they are both `VARCHAR`s -

```
SELECT t1.t1_field1, t1.t1_field2, t2.t2_field1, t2.t2_field2 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE LEFT(t1.t1_field1, 3) = LEFT(t2.t2_field1, 3);
```

I don't have S4 HANA to hand, but this is standard SQL and according to the documentation I Googled, it should work for Sybase which might be related?

Comment: The SQL query runs successfully on HANA database :) We can also use SUBSTRING() function. It fetches the same data. Here is how: SELECT *
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE substring(t1.t1_field1, 1, 3) = substring(t2.t2_field1, 1, 3);